# Can `this` be used when specifying a default value in typescript?

Tags: typescript, default-value

Is `this` in scope in the parameter list of a method in TypeScript?

Consider the [following code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Foo%20%7B%0D%0A%09constructor(public%20name)%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%09bar(str%3A%20string%20%3D%20this.name)%20%7B%20console.log(str)%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20f%20%3D%20new%20Foo(%22Yo%22)%3B%0D%0Af.bar()%3B%0D%0A):

```
class Foo {
    constructor(public name) {}
    bar(str: string = this.name) { console.log(str); }
}

let f = new Foo("Yo");
f.bar();
```

The default value of `str` is specified using `this` even though we're not inside an instance method's body.

Currently (in typescript 1.8) this works since it's transpiled to:

```
Foo.prototype.bar = function (str) {
    if (str === void 0) { str = this.name; }
    console.log(str);
};
```

So `this` is used *inside* the method but is this specified to be legal?

I couldn't find an answer to this with a cursory glance at the [specification](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md).

**Note:** This isn't legal in [C++](http://ideone.com/aQVy6S) which makes me question whether it's an intended feature or just an artefact of the transpilation process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the section [8.3.1 Constructor Parameters](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#831-constructor-parameters) it is explicitly stated that using `this` in *constructor* parameter default value expressions is an error.

In the section [8.4.2 Member Function Declarations](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#842-member-function-declarations) there is no mention of any errors of using `this` in default value expressions in ordinary class methods (non-constructors).

Section [6.6 Code Generation](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#66-code-generation) finally explains that the code is generated in the form of:

```
if (<Parameter> === void 0) { <Parameter> = <Default>; }
```

*Where Parameter is the parameter name and Default is the default value expression.*

In other words, current specification explicitly allows using `this` in parameter default value expressions, except in constructor.

Your code is perfectly valid according to spec.

Answer (score 4):

**Yes.** It is valid according to EcmaScript 6 [specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-function-definitions) and the TypeScript transpiler should treat it as such.

As default arguments are evaluated at call time, you can even use method calls and other arguments in the default value.

Comment: Do you know where in the es6 spec?

Comment: [Here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-function-definitions) in the specs. Also, a nice overview is given [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/cs/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters), pointing out that default arguments get evaluated at call time.